# How to fix No query results for model [App\User] settingedit in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.6 and  mysql. in My application i am going to show for edit current loging user name and email. this is User Model

```
public function scopeUserr($query)
{
     return $query->where('name',Auth::user()->name);

}
```

and UserController

```
public function settingedit()
{
    $users = User::userr()->get();
    return view('users.settingedit')->withUsers($users);
}
```

and My user data edit link is as following,

```
<a href="/users/settingedit" class="btn btn-primary">Update User</a>
```

and route is like this,

```
Route::get('users/settingedit', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@settingedit',
    'as'=> 'users.settingedit',
  ]);
```

but when I click Update User link following error is occured,

```
2/2) NotFoundHttpException

No query results for model [App\User] settingedit
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: What is `userr()->get();` ?

Comment: it is model scope

Comment: No, any comments